# Updating one to many relationship

Tags: database, relational-database, postgresql-9.3

I need some help in updating some fields in the db in two one-to-many relationships between 3 tables.

I have the current setup `farmer` that has many `box` that have many `fruits`.

Each farmer has a waranty period in days (an int column), each fruit has an expiry date (that depends on the delivery period `NOW() - fruit.expiry_date > farmer.days`)

My goal is to set the box as expired, but only if all the fruits in the box are expired.

This is what I've ended up with:

```
UPDATE
    boxes
SET
    expired = true
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT
        boxes.id
    FROM
        fruit, boxes, farmer
    WHERE
        fruit.box_id = boxes.id AND
        boxes.farmer_id = farmer.id AND
        DATE_PART('day', now() - fruit.expiry_date) > farmer.waranty_days AND
        boxes.expired = FALSE
)
```

The problem is that I got stuck, and have no idea on how to exclude the boxes that do not have all the fruits expired.
I've also tried to add a count, then left join the result, but still it was not working properly.

Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

A different way of thinking about the problem is that you want to identify boxes that contain no fresh fruit. Try something like this:

```
UPDATE boxes
INNER JOIN farmer ON boxes.farmer_id = farmer.id
SET boxes.expired = true
WHERE NOT boxes.expired
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM fruit
  WHERE boxes.id = fruit.box_id
  AND DATE_PART('day', now() - fruit.expiry_date) <= farmer.waranty_days
)
```

Another query that should do the same thing:

```
UPDATE boxes
INNER JOIN farmer ON boxes.farmer_id = farmer.id
LEFT JOIN fruit ON boxes.id = fruit.box_id
               AND DATE_PART('day', now() - fruit.expiry_date) <= farmer.waranty_days
SET boxes.expired = true
WHERE NOT boxes.expired AND fruit.id IS NULL
```